# Why is kivy not working in Visual Studio code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, kivy

I was writing a piece of code with kivy with all the packages installed.

When I run the code it still shows "No module named kivy".

The modules were installed from both the command prompt and the VS code terminal though this code had worked fine just a few days ago. Today i opened it and it showed me this error

This is my code

```py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from database import DataBase


class CreateAccountWindow(Screen):
    namee = ObjectProperty(None)
    email = ObjectProperty(None)
    password = ObjectProperty(None)

    def submit(self):
        if self.namee.text != "" and self.email.text != "" and self.email.text.count("@") == 1 and self.email.text.count(".") > 0:
            if self.password != "":
                db.add_user(self.email.text, self.password.text, self.namee.text)

                self.reset()

                sm.current = "login"
            else:
                invalidForm()
        else:
            invalidForm()

    def login(self):
        self.reset()
        sm.current = "login"

    def reset(self):
        self.email.text = ""
        self.password.text = ""
        self.namee.text = ""


class LoginWindow(Screen):
    email = ObjectProperty(None)
    password = ObjectProperty(None)

    def loginBtn(self):
        if db.validate(self.email.text, self.password.text):
            MainWindow.current = self.email.text
            self.reset()
            sm.current = "main"
        else:
            invalidLogin()

    def createBtn(self):
        self.reset()
        sm.current = "create"

    def reset(self):
        self.email.text = ""
        self.password.text = ""


class MainWindow(Screen):
    n = ObjectProperty(None)
    created = ObjectProperty(None)
    email = ObjectProperty(None)
    current = ""

    def logOut(self):
        sm.current = "login"

    def on_enter(self, *args):
        password, name, created = db.get_user(self.current)
        self.n.text = "Account Name: " + name
        self.email.text = "Email: " + self.current
        self.created.text = "Created On: " + created


class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass


def invalidLogin():
    pop = Popup(title='Invalid Login',
                  content=Label(text='Invalid username or password.'),
                  size_hint=(None, None), size=(400, 400))
    pop.open()


def invalidForm():
    pop = Popup(title='Invalid Form',
                  content=Label(text='Please fill in all inputs with valid information.'),
                  size_hint=(None, None), size=(400, 400))

    pop.open()


kv = Builder.load_file("my.kv")

sm = WindowManager()
db = DataBase("users.txt")

screens = [LoginWindow(name="login"), CreateAccountWindow(name="create"),MainWindow(name="main")]
for screen in screens:
    sm.add_widget(screen)

sm.current = "login"


class MyMainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return sm


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyMainApp().run()
```

[image]

Comment: install kivy for the interpreter you are using

Comment: @luigigi can you pls ellaborate on tht?

Comment: you probably installed kivy for a different interpreter/python-version. so either you have to choose an interpreter in VS code which has kivy installed, or you have to install kivy for the interpreter you are using right now. you can see the path to the python your are using in the error message

Comment: ok ty @luigigi i will try it out...which interepreter shud i be using?...in vs code

Comment: you should learn about the concept of virtual environments. there is no answer on what interpreter you should use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As people said in the comments, the reason is that the Python environment used by the terminal does not contain modules.

Solution: Please select the Python environment where the module "kivy" is installed in the lower left corner of VS Code, and use the shortcut key Ctrl+Shift+` to open a new VS Code terminal, it will automatically enter the selected environment.

check: We can use the command "`pip --version`" or "`python --version`" to check which Python the terminal is using and the module is installed in this location:

[image]

Reference: [Python environment in VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_select-and-activate-an-environment).

Comment: @Eishaan_Siingh  -Has this problem been resolved?

Comment: No actually I am a beginner coder and I am still trying to find the path i downloaded my Kivy files to, but yes I have actually figured how to make a virtual environment in VS Code thanks to you....hopefully I will be able to figure this out...Thank You very much though

Answer (score 0):

You just need to select the right version of python with which you installed kivy.
Click at the bottom part as indicated in the image below to select the right one.
[Change python interpreter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pjtgk.png)